# Function setTimeout JS output different result every time compile

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("A");
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("B");
  }, 100);
}, 200);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("C");
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("D");
  }, 200);
}, 100);
```

I execute the code above in Chrome Dev tool

The **first time** I run the code, the output is:

```
C A D B
```

Then I clear console and run the code again

The **second time**, the output is:

```
C A B D
```

Can some one explain for me why?

Comment: You've set two things to occur at the exact same time, but in a context where only one can occur at once, running on a non-deterministic non-realtime platform.

Comment: For me, the output is not changed for each run

Comment: Cool. A random generator based on how busy the parser and the processor is

Answer (score 0):

Any of those two can occur and technically, there is nothing wrong in it. The important thing is that the first output should be `C` which would appear after 100ms since program execution and `A` should appear in 100ms later. Then both `D` and `B` would appear around 100ms after `A`.

1st case

[image]

2nd case

[image]

In both cases, the console needs 1ms delay to print next output. Because it can't execute both `console.log()` at the very same time.